How to properly scale an SVG mask within a container element?
I'm trying to apply an SVG mask to a div element, but I'm encountering an issue where the mask is not scaling correctly with the container. The mask appears to overflow the container, showing only part of the masked content. I am aware that the SVG is 4000 x 7000 but there surely is a way to scale down, right?
In the attached image, you can see how the plain SVG, and then the mask made out of it (the goal is to apply the gradient effect using the mask).
Below you can also find the code for both of the shown examples:
simple SVG:


<html>
    <head>   
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: beige;
            }

            .logo {
                width: 50%;
                max-width: 300px;
                min-width: 150px;
                z-index: 10;
                aspect-ratio: 4.5;
                margin: 10px 0 25px;
            }

            .wrapper {
                width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                flex-direction: column;
            }

            .scale {
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                font-size: 15;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <svg class="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 7000 4000">
                <path d="M 3000,3000 L 5000,0 L 7000,3000 Z" />
                <path d="M 2000,3000 L 0,0 L 4000,0 Z"/>
            </svg>
            <div class="scale">
                30px
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>



masked gradient:


<html>
    <head>   
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: beige;
            }

            .logo {
                width: 50%;
                max-width: 300px;
                min-width: 150px;
                z-index: 10;
                aspect-ratio: 4.5;
                margin: 10px 0 25px;
            }

            svg {
                position: absolute;
            }

            .wrapper {
                width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                flex-direction: column;
            }

            @keyframes logoGradientAnimation {
                0%   { background-position:  100%; }
                100% { background-position: -100%; }
            } 

            .gradient {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                object-fit: cover;
                -webkit-mask-image: url(#logo-mask);
                mask-image: url(#logo-mask);
                background: linear-gradient(135deg, black 60%, #ea3c96, black 75%);
                animation: 3s cubic-bezier(.25,.50,.75,.50) infinite logoGradientAnimation;
                background-size: 200%;
                mask-size: contain;
            }

            mask > path {
                fill: white !important;
            }

            .scale {
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                font-size: 15;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 7000 4000">
                <defs>
                    <mask id="logo-mask">
                        <path d="M 3000,3000 L 5000,0 L 7000,3000 Z" />
                        <path d="M 2000,3000 L 0,0 L 4000,0 Z"/>
                    </mask>
                </defs>
            </svg>
            <div class="logo">
                <div class="gradient">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="scale">
                30px
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>



I've tried setting the width and height of the SVG to 100%, and also trying to set maskUnits & maskContentUnits but the mask still overflows the .logo container. How can I ensure that the mask scales correctly with the element it is applied to?
Any advice is very welcome!

Have you reviewed the documentation for mask?

Thank you for your reply! I have, but didn't get to any conclusion that could help. mask-size attribute should be my sure fix for the problem, but the mask does not react in any way when I apply mask-size.

Can you edit your question to show what you've tried with mask-size?

Sure! I have tested the mask-size attribute with the following values: 1%, 100%, contain, cover, auto, and just now 10px in order to try every kind of value. I am sure that I am getting something wrong, and I don't know what to do because it seems to me that nothing gets me closer to the desired outcome.

Apparently, the mask-size property has no effect on inline SVG references.
As a workaround you may convert your mask SVG to a data URL:
mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 7000 4000'><path d='M 3000 3000 L 5000 0 L 7000 3000 Z'/><path d='M 2000 3000 L 0 0 L 4000 0 Z' /></svg>");



body {
  background-color: beige;
}

.logo {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 150px;
  z-index: 10;
  aspect-ratio: 7/4;
  margin: 10px 0 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.gradient {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 7000 4000'><path d='M 3000 3000 L 5000 0 L 7000 3000 Z'/><path d='M 2000 3000 L 0 0 L 4000 0 Z' /></svg>");
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, black 60%, #ea3c96, black 75%);
  animation: 3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.5) infinite logoGradientAnimation;
  background-size: 200%;
  mask-size: cover;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.scale {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 15;
}

@keyframes logoGradientAnimation {
  0% {
    background-position: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -100%;
  }
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="gradient">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scale">
    30px
  </div>
</div>




StackOverflow tells me to avoid comments such as thanks, but thanks a lot, it is an obscurity I have not thought about and probably would have not, if it wasn't for your answer. Cheers!

My pleasure. In fact the mask and clip-path implementations are quite confusing. A lot of properties are still not working consistantly and in case of clip-path we don't have something like clip-size. Hopefully we'll get better ways to mask/clip elements in CSS
